# Как сделать разблокировку уровней и подсветку уже пройденных. Unity

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, ui

Пытаюсь сделать хоть что то похожее на игру и хочу сделать несколько уровней.

В этом меню можно выбрать уровень.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу чтобы до прохождения первого уровня нельзя было попасть на второй, а также подсветку кнопки выбора уровня другим цветом, если он уже был пройден.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: При загрузке списка уровней проверяй какой уровень пройден какой нет и в соответствии с этим меняй цвет кнопки/свойство interactable у кнопки/спрайт/все что придет в голову. В чем вопрос то?

Answer (score 3):

На сцену разместите замки(закрыто), а в старте делайте их неактивными.
Сохраняйте с помощью класса `PlayerPrefs`.

Например, при прохождении уровня сохраняйте:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("level", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("level", 0) + 1);
```

А при заходе в меню(`Start()`):

```
int level = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("level", 0);
for(int i = 0; i < level; i++){
     //делайте что-нибудь с массивом спрайтов
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для другого цвета можешь просто создать другой спрайт или перекрасить этот, а при открытии этого меню каждый раз проверять какие уровни доступны, а какие нет. На доступный пусть ставится эта текстурка, а на закрытый - другая. Я говорю как, конкретно можно посмотреть "в интернетах".

Для запрета на открытие недоступных уровней ничего сложного не нужно. Создайте переменную количества открытых уровней и при попытке открытия оного проверяйте, меньше ли число нужного или нет. *В общем:*

В коде действия при нажатии проверяем, меньше или равно (<= в C#, Python и большинстве других языков) это число, чем число уровня. True - открываем уровень, False - не открываем.

Comment: Перекрашивать самим Unity тоже можно, как предложил человек ниже, но сомневаюсь, что будет красиво выглядеть.

Answer (score -2):

Создайте статичную переменную:

```
public static int MaxFinishedLevel = 0
```

после прохождения каждого уровня проверяйте:

```
if (thisLevel > MaxFinishedLevel) {
    MaxFinishedLevel = thisLevel
}
```

тем самым в переменной будет храниться самый больший пройденный уровень. А затем в меню при создании кнопки вы просто проверяете текст кнопки, и если он меньше наибольшего пройденного уровня, ставьте ее серой, а иначе - зеленой:

```
x = Instantiate(Prefab, position, rotation)
if (x >= MaxFinishedLevel) {
    x.GetComponent<Renderer>().mayerial.color = Color.green
}
```